# Get the active tool in Python

Tags: python, scripting, interface, tools

How can I get(not set) the active tool in Python? I know there is:

```
>>> bpy.context.workspace.tools.from_space_view3d_mode("EDIT_MESH", create=False).idname
'builtin.knife'
```

But it begs the question: How can I get the current "space view3d mode"(`EDIT_MESH` in this case)? I tried:

```
>>> bpy.context.object.mode
'EDIT'
```

But it returned things like `EDIT` and can't be used for `bpy.context.workspace.tools.from_space_view3d_mode`.

Comment: `context.mode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
>>> bpy.context.mode
```

options are [EDIT_MESH’, ‘EDIT_CURVE’, ‘EDIT_SURFACE’, ‘EDIT_TEXT’, ‘EDIT_ARMATURE’, ‘EDIT_METABALL’, ‘EDIT_LATTICE’, ‘POSE’, ‘SCULPT’, ‘PAINT_WEIGHT’, ‘PAINT_VERTEX’, ‘PAINT_TEXTURE’, ‘PARTICLE’, ‘OBJECT’, ‘PAINT_GPENCIL’, ‘EDIT_GPENCIL’, ‘SCULPT_GPENCIL’, ‘WEIGHT_GPENCIL’]

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.mode